# RegEx for the string at the beginning of which there may be a version

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So, my program can accept strings like:

- `v00240004 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`
- `v0345 Duis nec eleifend nulla..`

and also a string without a version number:

- `Vivamus blandit et nibh nec placerat.`
- `In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti.`

I tried to write a regular expression to remove the version from the string. And it came out something like this: `/^.*?\s/`. It finds a match for the version and successfully replaces it with an empty string. But the problem is that it also works on strings without a version. That is, it removes the first word before the space.

So, my question is, how do I write a regular expression that works only on sentences starting with the letter "v" followed by numbers and replaces the version before the first space?

Example: A program receives 2 strings. The first `v0255 Example1 string1` and the second `Example2 string2`. The result after the regular expression should be `Example1 string1` and `Example2 string2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex is going to help you match only those strings which have first word before space as 'v' then version number.

> /^v\d.*?\s/gm

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
^v.*?\s
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/W2kl9l/1).